# Update ngFor on Angular APP

Tags: angularjs

I'm  trying build a component on my Angular app and get some problems. Let me explain...

I'm have this ngFor:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let processo of processos; let i = index; trackBy: trackById;">
```

on my component.ts i have this:

```
 processos: Array<any>
```

When i try add a new process, i receive a new doc, and storage then on my LocalStorage:

```
            this.advogadoService.addProcess(data)
                .subscribe(
                    process => {
                        this.updateService.update(process, 'processos');
                        this.processos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('processos'));
                        this.update(process._id);
                        resolve(process);
                    },
                    err => reject(err.json().message)
                )
```

So far, all works fine. I received the data, and update my view.
Now, my problems began...

I have this code:

```
    let updateData = Observable.interval(30000)
        .take(60)
        .flatMap(() => {
            return this.advogadoService.getOne(id)
        })

    this.search = updateData.subscribe(
        doc => {
            if(doc.processType) {
                this.updateService.update(doc, 'processos');
                this.processos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('processos'));
                this.stopNow();

                iziToast.success({
                    title: 'Processo atualizado',
                    message: `O processo ${doc.processNumber}, foi atualizado com sucesso!`,
                    icon: 'fa fa-bell-o',
                    layout: 2,
                    balloon: true,
                    timeout: 10000,
                })
            }
        }
    )

}

stopNow() {
    this.search.unsubscribe()

}
```

This code try 60 times, in intervals of 30 seconds get updated data was send before. When i receive the new data, put him on LocalStore, and update my view with this command:

```
this.processos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('processos'));
```

but my view not refresh with the new data, until i'm click in some object on the on my view, like on button for exemple.

I need update my view every time when i receive a new data.

What the best way i'm can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular's ngOnChanges is a good solution for this kind of scenario, because it's a life cycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes. More info here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html

Comment: Already try this... not work in my case... Maybe i done for wrong way.. do you can send an example? Thanks.